# Selection from dropdown lists based on index rather than value

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have this 'select' dropdown list on the website:

```
<select id="customQuestion0" class="form-control maxCharLimit" data-bind="'css':{'inputError': verificationFailed}, 'attr':{'id':'customQuestion' + $index(), tabindex:tabIdx},hasFocus:isSelected,  options: answers, optionsText:'answer', optionsCaption:$parent.chooseOneText, value:selectedAnswer, optionsValue:'answerKey'" id="customQuestion0" tabindex="13">
    <option value="">Choose One...</option>
    <option value="253133968">Doulos Email / Website</option>
    <option value="253133969">Cadence Email/Website</option>
    <option value="253133970">A colleague / friend</option>
    <option value="253133971">Other professional network (eg LinkedIn, Twitter)</option>
</select>
```

In the Tampermonkey script I can select e.g. option `Duolos Email / Website` with:

```
var formCustomQuestion1 = document.getElementById('customQuestion0')
formCustomQuestion0.value = '253133968'
```

But unfortunately this value `253133968` can change. Is there any way to be able to simply select item #1 in the script (starting the numbering at 0), disregarding the `value`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex

Comment: With this method I can get the index of the selected element. I need to select the item based on the index.

Comment: This isn't a read-only property, you can also assign a value to it ...

Answer (score 0):

It is working simply with:

```
formCustomQuestion0.selectedIndex = '1'
```